# vcredist_x86: the message install.res.????.dll comes up

Tags: vcredist

Our setup runs vcredist_x86.exe with Parameter [/qb to make it silent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/03/26/9513328.aspx). This works on all of our test systems, but unfortunately the installation still shows a message on a customer computer.

Please look at the image below - does anyone guess or know the origin of this message? I couldn't find anything here and on Google, [someone](http://www.ureader.com/msg/1453314.aspx) said that it happens for English Windows XP (which the customer has) but not on the German.

InnoSetup has full administrative rights and lauches vcredist_x86.exe version 9.0.21022.8 in its [Run] section. Our application is not written in VC, but used the GAUSS Run-Time Engine which is.

[image: While InnoSetup's 'Finishing installation...' is shown, the message install.res.????.dll comes up]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, whe tried to install vcredist_x86 with different from OS language (Windows 2003 Eng and vncredist Rus), when i download vcredist with proper language, it install successfully.

Also, you can see install log in %TEMP%\dd_vcredist*.txt
In my case it was said:

```
[06/29/12,13:10:31] ========== Logging started ==========
[06/29/12,13:10:31] =====================================
[06/29/12,13:10:31] Failed to set lang to requested lang code 1033
[06/29/12,13:10:31] Failed to set lang to OS language 1033
[06/29/12,13:10:31] ***ERROR EVENT*** : Failed last resort to set lang to ENU - no resources
[06/29/12,13:10:36] =========== Logging ended ===========
[06/29/12,13:10:36] =====================================
```

Answer (score 4):

*Just for the record, because I landed on this page while looking for a solution:*

I had to download the SP1 version of the executable file, [available here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092).

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056812/where-to-download-vcredist) might be useful as well.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me (running 7 ultimate in UK english)