# Where to download vcredist?

Tags: msdn, vcredist, technet

I feel a little stupid asking this question, but I hope that this might be helpful to others as well.

Background: We/I are developing some software with **Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (VC9)**. We would like to provide the `vcredist` along the software on the cd.

Now, I am used to ask google "download vcredist 2008 sp1" and usually it leads me to the following (also bookmarked) web pages:

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582 (32 bit)
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092 (64 bit)

I think I have downloaded different versions (9.0.30729.**01** and later 9.0.30729.**17**) from that same URL as they came available. Today, only the **.17** is available on that page. Now, a customer complained and told me that there is a 9.0.30729.**6161** available, but I can't find it. The closest I could get was 9.0.30729.**5677**:

- When I searched google for that specific version, it lead me to this page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2538243 which is saying, that a security update is available.
- The linked Security Bulletin https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms11-025 lists the vcredist 2008 sp1 as affected and as a new link to something that seems to be an updated version of the vcredist 2008 sp1, although it has a slightly different name, in that it also bears the "mfc" in it's name: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368
- File names, file sizes and version numbers suggest these are updated versions of the vcredist 2008 sp1. This is the version 9.0.30729.**5677**

Is there ONE URL where I can always pull the newest version ?

Is there some kind of notification system (email list, rss-feed, ...) that informs me about a new vcredist ?

Comment: Gosh! Years later - still the same problem! Where are those files hiding??? I really don't want to know how many hours developer life-time was wasted on searching for these files. W** is wrong with Microsofts software distribution? An auto-indexed download folder would suffice!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can download the VC++ redistributables at:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003

As of now, the latest are:

- Visual Studio 2005 (VC++ 8.0) SP1 w/ MFC Security Update: `8.0.61001` (`8.0.61000` for x86)
- Visual Studio 2008 (VC++ 9.0) SP1 w/ MFC Security Update: `9.0.30729.6161` (erroneously shown as `9.0.30729.5677` both on the microsoft.com page and in file properties of the installers)
- Visual Studio 2010 (VC++ 10.0) SP1 w/ MFC Security Update: `10.0.40219.325`
- Visual Studio 2012 (VC++ 11.0) Update 4: `11.0.61030.0`
- Visual Studio 2013 (VC++ 12.0) Update 5: `12.0.40664.0`
- Visual Studio 2015 (VC++ 14.0) Update 3: `14.0.24215.1`
- Visual Studio 2017 (VC++ 14.1): `14.16.27012.6`
- Visual Studio 2019 (VC++ 14.2): `14.25.28508.3`
- Visual Studio 2022 (VC++ 14.3): `14.38.33135.0`

**Note:** The 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022 packages share the same runtime files, hence only the latest of the series is required.

For additional versioning information, see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B

Comment: Note that the binaries with 2012 update 4 (`11.0.61030.0`) have version `11.0.60610.1` for the ATL and MFC binaries, and `11.0.51106.1` for everything else, e.g. msvcp110.dll and msvcr110.dll.